# Decoding IPFIX packets using Python

Tags: python-2.7, netflow

I want to parse the ipfix packet over udp from openvswitch, 
Is there a lib in python 2.7 could help me do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/britram/python-ipfix is the definitive Python IPFIX library, with good [documentation](https://britram.github.io/python-ipfix/), but it currently only supports Python 3.3+.

There is a [ticket open](https://github.com/britram/python-ipfix/issues/2) to investigate adding a Python 2.7 backport, but given that Python 2.7 will [End of Life in January 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) this seems unlikely to happen.